# Oauth : Where to get userId for AuthorizationCodeFlow . createAndStoreCredential?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, credentials

I work on google app project and I am struggling a bit with java oauth library (1.10.1-beta).

I followed closely : http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Authorization_code_flow

Problem is that I dont know from where I should get userId or userEmail. I know there is userinfo API but I am actually trying to create Credentials, so I cannot access userinfo API AFIAK.

My application work nicely on localhost (because of test@example.com user is always there) but fails miserably when deployed in google engine environment (NullPointerException user.getUserId()).

```
// we ask for token because we got authCode
GoogleTokenResponse gTokenResponse = userUtils.getFlow().newTokenRequest(authCode).setRedirectUri(userUtils.getRedirectUri()).execute();

//trying to search for user email / id /  whatever
User user = UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser();

//user is null -> nullPointerException is thrown 
userUtils.getFlow().createAndStoreCredential(gTokenResponse, user.getUserId());
```

Could you please point out a flaw in my use-case or give me a hint ? I searched a lot in SDK samples,Stackoverflow and here but there is not many implementations.

PS: In method [AuthorizationCodeFlow.createAndStoreCredential](http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/source/browse/google-oauth-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/AuthorizationCodeFlow.java?name=1.10.1-beta)(...) is userId mandatory only when you use persistent storage for Credentials and yes i am using that so userId cannot be null in my case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing OAUTH (authorization) before you identified your user (authentication). You must redirect your user to the login page when he is not logged in :

```
UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser() == null
```

You do that by redirecting the user to the loginUrl :

```
String loginUrl = userService.createLoginURL(request.getOriginalRef().toString());
```

The next time the user arrives at your app, he will be logged in, and you can ask for the userId.

Comment: But given code runs after user grants access of application so in that  situation application have to know who is logged in google account.

Comment: if UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser() == null
then I am afraid the user is not logged into his google account